# restricting the uploading files size in php

Tags: php, html, file-upload, upload

I am working with multiple file upload in PHP and I also fixed an upload limit of 10MB using the following HTML commands in an upload form PHP file:

```
   <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000"> 
   <input id="infile" type="file" name="infile[]" multiple="true" />
```

In the PHP file that takes care of upload function I was initially expecting that if I try to upload a file of size greater than 10MB then the function call statement

```
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['infile']['tmp_name'][$i], $dir . $fPath);
```

will fail and I can show an "Error upload file of size less than 10MB" message. But it didnt happen. It was trying to upload and it didnt display any error message as expected.

So I tried to restrict the file size specifically in the code by using the if statement as:

```
  if ($_FILES["infile"]["size"][$i]<10000000) 
    {
       move_uploaded_file($_FILES['infile']['tmp_name'][$i], $dir . $fPath);
    }
  else
    echo "error";
```

But still it doesnt echo error as expected. Can anyone please point out the mistake I am doing here?

Comment: Are you sure that your file is more than 10,000,000 bytes? Maybe it's showing as 10MB with rounding?

Comment: the MAX_FILE_SIZE is just for PHP post-upload checking. Correct way is to set the system parameter via php.ini or ini_set function

Comment: thanks for your comments but shouldnt the "error" msg appear when the file size if more than 10MB by the if statement that is in the code i mentioned here. Also I forgot to mention that the file of size greater than 10MB is not getting uploaded here.

Comment: can u post the html part of the form....

Comment: Sorry here is the main part:                                     <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload_hal_mult.php?id=<?php echo $f_id;?>" >                   
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000"> 
<input id="infile" type="file" name="infile[]" multiple="true" />
<input type="submit" value="upload" name="file_uploaded"  / >

Comment: What is the values for `$i` in the php code...it must start from 0.. if you have only 1 file it should be like `$_FILES["infile"]["size"][0]`

Comment: This is the short form of for loop I am using for uploading multiple files:                                                             for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['infile']['name']); $i++) 
{
if($_FILES["infile"]["size"][$i]>MAX_SIZE)
  echo "File uploaded exceeds maximum upload size";
else                                                                { move_uploaded_file($_FILES['infile']['tmp_name'][$i], $dir . $fPath))
echo "Upload is successful\n";
}
I get sometimes "Upload is successful" or sometimes nothing. But the file is not getting uploaded as expected

Comment: Give the whole html and php files, we probably don't have enough info.

Comment: Ok, here is the upload form php file code:                                    <?php
$f_id= $_GET["id"];
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '10M');
?>
<title>Upload File</title>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload_hal_mult.php?id=<?php echo $f_id;?>" > 
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000"> 
<input id="infile" type="file" name="infile[]" multiple="true" />
<input type="submit" value="upload" name="file_uploaded"  / > 
<br>
<br>
</form>

Comment: "upload_hal_mult.php" file:<?php $f_id= $_GET["id"];
$dir_name="dir_".$f_id;
if (!is_dir($dir_name))
mkdir($dir_name);
$dir=$dir_name."/";
$file_realname = $_FILES['infile']['name'];  contd...

Comment: for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['infile']['name']); $i++) 
{$ext = substr(strrchr($_FILES['infile']['name'][$i], "."), 1); 
$fname = substr($_FILES['infile']['name'][$i],0,strpos($_FILES['infile']['name'][$i], ".")); 
$fPath = $fname."_(".substr(md5(rand() * time()),0,4).")".".$ext";
if($_FILES["infile"]["size"][$i]>1000000)
echo "File uploaded exceeds maximum upload size"; 
else{move_uploaded_file($_FILES['infile']['tmp_name'][$i], $dir . $fPath);echo "Upload is successful\n";}}?>

Answer (score 2):

You can add the following line to your target script that handle your form:

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '10M');
```

Or if you can access your php.ini, just change the following :

```
upload_max_filesize = 10M
```

Manual page : http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

Comment: Thanks Ninsuo, but it doesnt help me. I am just trying to print out an error message if the file size if large thats all. But the if statement is not helping me. Please let me know if you need any more info

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["file_uploaded"])){
    $f_id= $_GET["id"]; 
    $dir_name="dir_hal_".$f_id; 
    $u=0; 
    if(!is_dir($dir_name))
    {
        mkdir($dir_name); 
    }
    $dir=$dir_name."/"; 
    $file_realname = $_FILES['infile']['name'];
    $c=count($_FILES['infile']['name']);
    for($i = 0;$i<$c;$i++) 
    {
        $ext = substr(strrchr($_FILES['infile']['name'][$i], "."), 1); 
        $fname = substr($_FILES['infile']['name'][$i],0,strpos($_FILES['infile']['name'][$i], "."));
        $fPath = $fname."_(".substr(md5(rand() * time()),0,4).")".".$ext"; 
        if($_FILES["infile"]["size"][$i]>10000000)
        {
            echo 'File uploaded exceeds maximum upload size.';
        }
        else{
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['infile']['tmp_name'][$i], $dir . $fPath)) 
            {
                $u=$u+1;
                echo "Upload is successful\n";
            }
            else 
            {
                echo "error\n"; 
            }
        }
    }
    if($u==$c)
    {
        echo "count is correct";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks Sherin, but this doesnt work as well. It tries to upload any file that is being selected and then it says nothing. no error message and also the file doesnt upload. Please let me know if you find any way out

Comment: ok sherin. for uploading form i created a php file as follows:          <?php
$f_id= $_GET["id"];
?>
<title>Upload File</title>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload_hal_mult.php?id=<?php echo $f_id;?>" > 
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000"> 
<input id="infile" type="file" name="infile[]" multiple="true" />
<input type="submit" value="upload" name="file_uploaded"  / > 
</form>

Comment: the "upload_hal_mult.php" is in two commments as follows:        
<?php
$f_id= $_GET["id"];
$dir_name="dir_hal_".$f_id;
$u=0;
if (!is_dir($dir_name))
mkdir($dir_name);
$dir=$dir_name."/";
$file_realname = $_FILES['infile']['name'];

Comment: contd..$c=count($_FILES['infile']['name']);for($i = 0;$i<$c;$i++) 
{$ext = substr(strrchr($_FILES['infile']['name'][$i], "."), 1); 
$fname = substr($_FILES['infile']['name'][$i],0,strpos($_FILES['infile']['name'][$i], "."));$fPath = $fname."_(".substr(md5(rand() * time()),0,4).")".".$ext";
if($_FILES["infile"]["size"][$i]>10000000)
die('File uploaded exceeds maximum upload size.');
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['infile']['tmp_name'][$i], $dir . $fPath))
{$u=$u+1;echo "Upload is successful\n";}else echo "error\n";
}if($u==$c)echo "count is correct";?>

Comment: if this is confusing to see, i am also willing to email u the code

Comment: There must be an else part for `if($_FILES["infile"]["size"][$i]>10000000)`, otherwise the remaining stmts are executed every time...

Comment: sorry I think I pasted the wrong code here, here is the for loop part: for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['infile']['name']); $i++) 
{
 $ext = substr(strrchr($_FILES['infile']['name'][$i], "."), 1); 
 $fname = substr($_FILES['infile']['name'][$i],0,strpos($_FILES['infile']['name'][$i], ".")); 
 $fPath = $fname."_(".substr(md5(rand() * time()),0,4).")".".$ext";
if($_FILES["infile"]["size"][$i]>1000000)
        echo "File uploaded exceeds maximum upload size"; 
    else { 
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['infile']['tmp_name'][$i], $dir . $fPath);
        echo "Upload is successful\n"; 
    }
}

Comment: hey this will sound crazy, but when I tried uploading the file with the code that you just posted here yesterday, I didnt get any error message when I uploaded a file of size>10MB, but when I added an else part to the initial if statement "if(isset($_POST["file_uploaded"])){", as "else { echo "error in file";} I got the message "error in file". I initially didnt have this if statement as I thought anyway the control goes to this php file, anyway I guess I will follow this approach. So basically a bigger file makes the "if(_POST)" statement fails!