# video file upload php

Tags: php, video, file-upload

Hi Can anyone tell me how to restict user from uploading the video files of large size and they should upload only specific type. They should be able to upload only 8mb files and not more than that. Below is my code.

```
        <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {

        $filename=$_FILES['file']['name'];
        $filesize=$_FILES['file']['size'];
        $filetype=$_FILES['file']['type'];
        $tmpfile=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $unique=str_shuffle("abcde").$filename;

        if ((($filetype == "video/avi")
    || ($filetype == "video/mpeg")
    || ($filetype == "video/mpg")
    || ($filetype == "video/mov")|| ($filetype == "video/wmv") || ($filetype == "video/rm") || ($filetype == "image/mp4"))
    && ($filesize < 8388608 and $filesize > 20))

{

    move_uploaded_file($tmpfile,"uploads/$unique");

        echo'file is uploaded';
}
        else
    {
        echo'failure in uploading';
    }





}


?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [restricting the uploading files size in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13152114/restricting-the-uploading-files-size-in-php)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code you provided, other than the missing PHP "?" at the very end

Comment: when i am trying to upload the video files larger in size it is showing the warning message Warning: POST Content-Length of 26246321 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0   insetead  of showing failure in uploading.

Comment: hello Lloyd Banks. There is no missing PHP "?" in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can also limit the file size in the HTML Form: `<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="8388608" />` although it will process the entire upload and then result in a failure.

You're best bet is to use jQuery to evaluate the selected file on Submit, with PHP server-side validation like you have as well.

EDIT1a: **jQuery** example: [Using jQuery, Restricting File Size Before Uploading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307679/using-jquery-restricting-file-size-before-uploading)

EDIT1b: Example PHP Upload Code from working site:

```
protected function handle_image_upload($frmFilesID = false, $thisFile = false) {

$fileName = $_FILES["$frmFilesID"]['name'][$thisFile];
$tmpName = $_FILES["$frmFilesID"]['tmp_name'][$thisFile];
if (!is_uploaded_file($tmpName)) { trigger_error("Security block.", E_USER_ERROR); return false; }
$fileSize = $_FILES["$frmFilesID"]['size'][$thisFile];
$fileType = $_FILES["$frmFilesID"]['type'][$thisFile];

// Evaluate File Size
if ($fileSize > '8388608') { trigger_error('File exceeds maximum size.', E_USER_ERROR); return false; }

// Make folder path if needed
$destPath = 'imgdir';
if (!is_dir($destPath) && !@mkdir($destPath, 0777, true)) { trigger_error("Could not create folder.", E_USER_ERROR); return false; }

// Test if file already exists (auto-rename?)
if (file_exists($destPath . '/' . $fileName)) {
    trigger_error("File already exists, rename the file and try again.", E_USER_ERROR);
    return false;
}

// Move uploaded file from tmp
if (move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $destPath . '/' . $fileName)) {
    return true;
} else {
    trigger_error("Invalid results.", E_USER_NOTICE);
    return false;
}

}
```

Call the function for each file being uploaded:

```
for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {
    $frmFilesID = "ImagesFormIdGoesHere";
    if (!handle_image_upload($frmFilesID, $i)) { echo "<br /><strong>NOTE:</strong> Failed to upload file $i..."; }
}
```

Comment: how can i do that in Jquery?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307679/using-jquery-restricting-file-size-before-uploading